# Ubuntu VirtualBox VM locks up frequently on Win8 host

Tags: macos, ubuntu, windows-8, virtualbox, vagrant

Using the same exact Vagrantfile to build an Ubuntu 12.04 x64 VM on both MacOS and Win8, I noticed that the VM locks up frequently (at least once per minute) on Windows. At first I thought it might be a terminal issue, so I tested SSHing with MinTTY, regular Cygwin non-tty bash, PuTTY, etc - all of which exhibit the same behavior. It's not limited to a single SSH session, as all sessions are locked simultaneously. I can't really get any diagnostic info from the machine while it's happening, but various places on the web suggest only using a single virtual CPU (no effect) or disabling VT-x/AMD-V (can't, guest is x64).

I assume it must be a difference in how VirtualBox behaves on Win8 vs MacOS since, again, it works flawlessly on MacOS. Is there anything I can do to further diagnose or potentially fix the issue? Happy to downgrade VBox if needed/use a beta/etc as well.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is for better performance on your Mac's VM, either the Mac has better ram, or the issue is a result of Windows being Windows (PCs are generally slower and less efficient than Macs, especially with 10.9)
The best solution is to not use VirtualBox and go for BootCamp. BootCamp allows you to dual boot Windows and OSX on any Mac, and because it's Apple supported
A. It's specifically engineered for the task
B. You don't have to run OSX while your Win 8 is running
BootCamp assistant is a utility preinstalled on your computer inside the Applications/Utilities folder.

Comment: I've used bootcamp extensively in the past, but I am not using a mac anymore - even so, the goal is not to replace VirtualBox or change my dev setup, but to diagnose/fix why it is behaving erratically in the first place.

Comment: Also, the Windows machine is ridiculously overpowered for running a small VM (512mb ram, 1 virtual CPU) - the locking isn't because I inherently need better VM performance, it's because there's something wrong with VirtualBox AFAICT.